# Collision detection of 2 gifs on canvas

Tags: html, canvas, collision-detection, kineticjs

I have several images already loaded on a canvas and i want to add simple collision detection (when any of them collide, show a message or change the color, etc).  I'm loading the images by way of:

```
// Taurus Image
    var taurusImg = new Kinetic.Image({
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      image: images.Taurus,
      width: 216,
      height: 75,
      name: 'image'
    });

    taurusGroup.add(taurusImg);

    taurusGroup.on('dragstart', function() {
      this.moveToTop();
    });

    // Truck Image
    var truckImg = new Kinetic.Image({
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      image: images.Truck,
      width: 950,
      height: 158,
      name: 'image'
    });

    truckGroup.add(truckImg);

    truckGroup.on('dragstart', function() {
      this.moveToTop();
    });
```

And i'm loading them in the sources:

```
var sources = {

    Taurus: 'content/taurus.gif',
    Truck: 'content/truck2.gif'
  };
```

after calling a function loadimages i thought i could use something like this:

```
function collides(a, b)
    {
        if (a.x < b.x + b.width &&
            a.x + a.width > b.x &&
            a.y < b.y + b.height &&
            a.y + a.height > b.y) return true;
    }
```

But nothings happening.  Do i need to load the images another way?  As i said they are all on the screen already and i'm able to drag them around i just can't get collision detection working.  Thank you so much for any help/advice you guys might have!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple possible issues here:

#### 1. Your `collides` function isn't referencing the correct object properties

If you're passing the Kinetic objects themselves, you'll want to use the accessor methods:

```
function rectanglesOverlap(r1, r2) {
  return (r1.x() < r2.x() + r2.width() &&
    r1.x() + r1.width() > r2.x() &&
    r1.y() < r2.y() + r2.height() &&
    r1.y() + r1.height() > r2.y());
}
```

#### 2. Are you running your collision detection?

```
layer.find('.image').on('dragmove', function() {
  detectCollisions();
});

function detectCollisions() {
  var images = layer.find('.image');
  images.stroke(null);

  for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
    for (var j=i+1; j<images.length; j++) {
      if ( rectanglesOverlap(images[i], images[j]) ) {
        images[i].stroke('red');
        images[j].stroke('red');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a fiddle demonstrating collision detection (it substitutes rectangles for your images):

http://jsfiddle.net/klenwell/z6zTA/

Comment: Thanks @klenwell i'm going to look at this right now.  Really appreciate it!  Been going nuts trying to figure this out!

Comment: i think i got this working but for some reason it's only working on the first 2 images or squares.  I have 8 images that can possibly collide.  NOt sure why it's only working if the first 2 images collide...

Comment: @user3812781 The logic in the detectCollisions function was a bit sloppy. It would be a good exercise to try to figure out why. Nevertheless, here's a cleaned up version: http://jsfiddle.net/klenwell/z6zTA/

Comment: @user3812781 You're welcome. Don't forget to click the answer's green checkmark.